# DOC/SVG to PDF conversion in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, svg, ms-word

I am creating a digital certificate with a number of images and custom fonts. I am trying the following :

1. Create Microsoft word document with placeholders and save it as an ´xml´ file. And dynamically replace the content in the placeholders and export it as an pdf file.
2. Create an svg file word document with placeholders. And dynamically replace the content in the placeholders and export it as an pdf file.

I am having some difficulty with alignments with (1). So, I prefer creating the certificate using Inkscape.

Any idea, what would be best approach ? Any 3rd party libraries which would help export

1. Doc to pdf
2. svg to pdf

BTW, I am running the script on a shared Linux host

Thanks

Comment: Why use a MS-Word format for that? Sounds much too complex for the purpose. Just implement the layout either in LaTeX or in fpdf (tfpdf) and all is fine. Especially it's going to look better that way.

Comment: It is easier to create the certificate in MS Word right. LaTeX would be too much work with all the alignment/using custom fonts.

Comment: Depends, some people prefer MS-Word, some prefer LaTeX, this is a question of ones personal favorite. What is undisputed however is that the result looks much more professional when using LaTeX. I don't know if that is important for you, though. But the main point: when _not_ using MS-Word formats the code you need for processing the input template is much easier. That is why I suggested it.

Comment: Use XSL FO for SVG to PDF